# Creating a modal window for images

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a modal so that when the user clicks something it will open a modal window of an image. So far I've got a basic one going using a basic script but the way it's done will only allow one to work at a time.

```
 <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            captionText.innerHTML = modalImg.alt;
        }
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
```

This method pretty obviously has the issue of selecting by specfic id. Would there be a way to re-write this so that it takes in the id and etc of whatever is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>Modal Caption</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="image" class="image">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1079020/pexels-photo-1079020.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Älter Text">
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="close-btn">
      <button onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="call-back-modal">
    <button onclick="callModal()">Call Modal</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.modal-container .modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: -700px;
  left: 25%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(32, 33, 36, .28);

}
.modal-caption h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.modal-container .call-back-modal {
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  top: -700px;
}

.modal-container .modal img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function callModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

  if (modal.style.top === "0px") {
        modal.style.top = "-700px";
    } else {
        modal.style.top = "0px";
    }
}

function closeModal(){
  var closeModal = document.getElementById("modal");
modal.style.top = "-700px";

}
```

**Live: [Demo](https://codepen.io/motahar_hossain/pen/xxwoKeM?editors=0010)**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want whenever the user clicks on a certain element, the modal is displayed.
Then instead call a function inline : `onclick="displayModal()"` for whatever you want to display a modal when it's clicked.

So it will look like this :

```
function displayModal(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            captionText.innerHTML = modalImg.alt;
        }
```